# C# WMI Error Message "Not Supported"

Tags: c#, .net, printing, wmi

I'm trying to install/add a networked printer on a remote computer using WMI. The below code works perfectly when i enter my local computer name but i get an error message "Not Supported" when i use any remote computer name. I looked up the WMI Error on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and read "Feature or operation is not supported." But also noticed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) they have a 'howto' add a new printer connection to a remote computer and there VBs example. I copied the VBs example and ran it and also recieved the same error "Not Supported". What am i missing? Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
        ConnectionOptions conOp = new ConnectionOptions();
        conOp.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        conOp.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
        conOp.EnablePrivileges = true;

        ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\pcname\ROOT\CIMV2", conOp);
        manScope.Connect();

        ManagementClass manClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Printer"), null);

        ManagementBaseObject inParams = manClass.GetMethodParameters("AddPrinterConnection");
        inParams["Name"] = @"\\server\printer";            

////////Error Occurs Here
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = manClass.InvokeMethod("AddPrinterConnection", inParams, null);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a printer to a different machine? I think WMI calls are version specific.

Comment: @Brandon I haven't tried to run this code "localy" on another machine if thats what your asking? The remote computers I'm attempting to install printers on do allow me to manually add a new printer though.

Comment: No I mean in the code for `ManagementScope manscope = new.... (@"\\pcname\ROOT....`, have you tried a different value in pcname? How many remote computers have you tried?

Comment: @Brandon Yes, i have tried multiple remote computer names and my typical test VMs.